# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-geolocation

I am fetching `latitude` and `longitude` using `GPS` in my `application`. I am using `GoogleApiClient` for this. I have an `Activity` named "**HomeActivity**" on which I have created a header and a `FrameLayout` to show other `fragments` on that `Activity`. I also have setting button on my header.

**Now the problem:**

In one of my fragment named "**A fragment**" I am fetching `latitude` and `longitude` and using it for some work. And on setting `button` I opens a `dialog` which immediately fetch current latitude and  longitude. But the problem is that when I am on "A fragment" and also open the `Dialog` then sometime my app got crashed and throw an error  i.e. "Already managing a `GoogleApiClient` with id 0". And error directly points to my `Dialog` code. I have done several hours of work and research but not able to resolve the problem. Please help.

**Code to open dialog from Setting button on HomeActivity's Header**

```
    // onClickListener on Setting button
      case R.id.setting:
            DialogSettings dc = new DialogSettings(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.this,"HomeActivity",HomeActivity.this);
            dc.show();
```

**Code for Dialog where we fetch latitude and longitude**

```
    public class DialogSettings extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {


    Context context;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;


    public DialogSettings(Activity a, Context context, String currentActivity, AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {
        super(a);
        this.context = context;
        this.currentActivity = currentActivity;
        this.appCompatActivity = appCompatActivity;
    }


    // point out error on this code
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        setUpGClient();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();

        googleApiClient.stopAutoManage((AppCompatActivity) context);
        googleApiClient.disconnect();

    }


    // point out error on this code 
    private synchronized void setUpGClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .enableAutoManage(((AppCompatActivity) context), 0, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }


}
```

**Code for "A Fragment" which also fetches Latitude and Longitude**

```
     public class UwLocalePolitieFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        googleApiClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }


    private synchronized void setUpGClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), 0, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        setUpGClient();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Change enableAutoManage(getActivity() ,0, this)

To enableAutoManage(getActivity(),1, this )